# Error while creating object from templated class

Tags: c++, class, templates, boost, eigen

I've been trying to find a way to sample random vectors from a multivariate normal distribution in C++, having both the mean vector and the covariance matrix, much like Matlab's `mvnrnd` function works. I've found relevant code for a class that implements this on [this page](http://lost-found-wandering.blogspot.pt/2011/05/sampling-from-multivariate-normal-in-c.html?showComment=1367509801687#c3303481847624571136), but I've been having some problems compiling it. I've created a header file that is being included on my main.cpp, and I'm trying to create an object of the `EigenMultivariateNormal` class:

```
MatrixXd MN(10,1);
MatrixXd CVM(10,10);

EigenMultivariateNormal <double,int> (&MN,&CVM) mvn;
```

The problem is I get a template-related error when compiling:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Scalar, int _size> class EigenMultivariateNormal’    
error:   expected a constant of type ‘int’, got ‘int’    
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘mvn’
```

I only have a superficial idea on how to work with templates, and I am by no means a cpp expert, so I was wondering what exactly am I doing wrong? Apparently I should have a `const` somewhere on my code.

Comment: Do u need to give it a number, like 10, rather than an "int"?

Comment: i think it wants you to use int value for the second template param, like EigenMultivariateNormal <double,42>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`template<class _Scalar, int _size> class EigenMultivariateNormal` is specialized template class. The first `class _Scalar` ask for a type but `int _size` ask for an int.

You should call it with a constant int instead of the type int as you did.
Secondly, your syntax to instance a new class EigenMultivariateNormal is wrong.
Try this instead:

```
EigenMultivariateNormal<double, 10> mvn (&MN, &CVM); // with 10 is the size
```

Answer (score 2):

That code's a bit old.  Here's a newer, possibly improved version.  There are probably still some bad things.  For example, I think it should be changed to use the `MatrixBase` instead of an actual `Matrix`.  That might let it optimize and better decide when it needs to allocate storage space or not.  This also uses the namespace `internal` which is probably frowned on, but it seems necessary to make use of Eigen's `NullaryExpr` which seems like the right thing to do.  There's usage of the dreaded `mutable` keyword.  That's necessary because of what Eigen thinks should be `const` when used in a `NullaryExpr`.
It's also a little annoying to rely on boost.  It seems that in C++11 the [necessary functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) have become standard.  Below the class code, there's a short usage sample.

The class `eigenmultivariatenormal.hpp`

```
#ifndef __EIGENMULTIVARIATENORMAL_HPP
#define __EIGENMULTIVARIATENORMAL_HPP

#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/normal_distribution.hpp>    

/*
  We need a functor that can pretend it's const,
  but to be a good random number generator 
  it needs mutable state.  The standard Eigen function 
  Random() just calls rand(), which changes a global
  variable.
*/
namespace Eigen {
namespace internal {
template<typename Scalar> 
struct scalar_normal_dist_op 
{
  static boost::mt19937 rng;                        // The uniform pseudo-random algorithm
  mutable boost::normal_distribution<Scalar> norm;  // The gaussian combinator

  EIGEN_EMPTY_STRUCT_CTOR(scalar_normal_dist_op)

  template<typename Index>
  inline const Scalar operator() (Index, Index = 0) const { return norm(rng); }
};

template<typename Scalar> 
boost::mt19937 scalar_normal_dist_op<Scalar>::rng;

template<typename Scalar>
struct functor_traits<scalar_normal_dist_op<Scalar> >
{ enum { Cost = 50 * NumTraits<Scalar>::MulCost, PacketAccess = false, IsRepeatable = false }; };

} // end namespace internal
/**
    Find the eigen-decomposition of the covariance matrix
    and then store it for sampling from a multi-variate normal 
*/
template<typename Scalar, int Size>
class EigenMultivariateNormal
{
  Matrix<Scalar,Size,Size> _covar;
  Matrix<Scalar,Size,Size> _transform;
  Matrix< Scalar, Size, 1> _mean;
  internal::scalar_normal_dist_op<Scalar> randN; // Gaussian functor


public:
  EigenMultivariateNormal(const Matrix<Scalar,Size,1>& mean,const Matrix<Scalar,Size,Size>& covar)
  {
    setMean(mean);
    setCovar(covar);
  }

  void setMean(const Matrix<Scalar,Size,1>& mean) { _mean = mean; }
  void setCovar(const Matrix<Scalar,Size,Size>& covar) 
  {
    _covar = covar;

    // Assuming that we'll be using this repeatedly,
    // compute the transformation matrix that will
    // be applied to unit-variance independent normals

    /*
    Eigen::LDLT<Eigen::Matrix<Scalar,Size,Size> > cholSolver(_covar);
    // We can only use the cholesky decomposition if 
    // the covariance matrix is symmetric, pos-definite.
    // But a covariance matrix might be pos-semi-definite.
    // In that case, we'll go to an EigenSolver
    if (cholSolver.info()==Eigen::Success) {
      // Use cholesky solver
      _transform = cholSolver.matrixL();
    } else {*/
      SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Matrix<Scalar,Size,Size> > eigenSolver(_covar);
      _transform = eigenSolver.eigenvectors()*eigenSolver.eigenvalues().cwiseMax(0).cwiseSqrt().asDiagonal();
    /*}*/

  }

  /// Draw nn samples from the gaussian and return them
  /// as columns in a Size by nn matrix
  Matrix<Scalar,Size,-1> samples(int nn)
  {
    return (_transform * Matrix<Scalar,Size,-1>::NullaryExpr(Size,nn,randN)).colwise() + _mean;
  }
}; // end class EigenMultivariateNormal
} // end namespace Eigen
#endif
```

Here's a simple program that uses it:

```
#include <fstream>
#include "eigenmultivariatenormal.hpp"
#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI REAL(3.1415926535897932384626433832795029)
#endif

/**
  Take a pair of un-correlated variances.
  Create a covariance matrix by correlating 
  them, sandwiching them in a rotation matrix.
*/
Eigen::Matrix2d genCovar(double v0,double v1,double theta)
{
  Eigen::Matrix2d rot = Eigen::Rotation2Dd(theta).matrix();
  return rot*Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<double,2,2>(v0,v1)*rot.transpose();
}

void main()
{
  Eigen::Vector2d mean;
  Eigen::Matrix2d covar;
  mean << -1,0.5; // Set the mean
  // Create a covariance matrix
  // Much wider than it is tall
  // and rotated clockwise by a bit
  covar = genCovar(3,0.1,M_PI/5.0);

  // Create a bivariate gaussian distribution of doubles.
  // with our chosen mean and covariance
  Eigen::EigenMultivariateNormal<double,2> normX(mean,covar);
  std::ofstream file("samples.txt");

  // Generate some samples and write them out to file 
  // for plotting
  file << normX.samples(1000).transpose() << std::endl;
}
```

And here's a plot showing the results.

[image: Two 2d Gaussian distributions]

Using the `SelfAdjointEigenSolver` is probably a lot slower than a Cholesky decomposition, but it is stable, even if the covariance matrix is singular.  If you know that your covariance matrices will always be full, then you could use that instead.  However, if you create the distribution rarely and sample from it often, then that's probably not a big deal.

Comment: Actually, the use I have in mind speed might indeed be an issue, am I am positive the covariance matrices are always positive definite, otherwise it would defeat the end purpose. So I assume the Cholesky approach is faster, as I need to iteratively sample values from the distribution, while changing the covariance and mean matrices and re-sample in the next iteration. What would be, however, the main advantage of using `MatrixBase` instead of `Matrix`?

Comment: @joaocandre When you create a Matrix object, it allocates memory for the entire matrix and stores data there.  When you create a MatrixBase object, if the data are part of an expression, then the values can sometimes be funneled through the expression to their final destinations without explicitly creating all of the intermediate storage.  I'm not totally sure how it works, but that's how things work internally in Eigen.

Comment: I'me getting several erros when compiling your code, the first of which: `ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘EIGEN_EMPTY_STRUCT_CTOR’ with no type [-fpermissive]`

Comment: @joaocandre That makes it sound like the Eigen libraries aren't getting included properly.  Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Eigen v2.0.17, available in Ubuntu repositories. Eigen  v3.1.0 is only available in the official repositories as a beta, so I did not installed it.

Comment: So, back to this problem, never really managed to compile it, tried with both eigen2 and eigen3 from Ubuntu repositories. I solved the above erro by adding `-std=gnu++11` option to g++, but now I am getting `eigen_multivariate_normal_v2.hpp:34:8: error: expected identifier before ‘<’ token`, among others. The line that seems to be causing the errors is `struct <scalar_normal_dist_op<Scalar>> functor_traits`. Should I try getting Eigen from their website and manually installing them?

Comment: @joaocandre It definitely needs Eigen 3 because they've made some significant internal changes.  The line that you've copied has been incorrectly reordered.  It should be: `struct functor_traits<scalar_normal_dist_op<Scalar> >`

Comment: Thank you it is working now. However, and this is something I've already noticed in the code that initially started this topic, the number generated are the same every time I run the code. Shouldn't they be stocastically generated? Otherwise there is no point in calling it a "random" generator.

Comment: @joaocandre That's why the random number generator is declared `static` and the distribution is `mutable`.  The `rng` maintains some changing internal state that allows each call to produce a different number.  This works fine for me.  If it's being cached, then something is going wrong.

Comment: Ah.  But you need to seed the random number generator with different numbers if you want different results from code execution to code execution.  I think this might be accomplished with something like this: `Eigen::internal::scalar_normal_dist_op::rng.seed((int)time(0));`

Comment: I just need them to be random every time I sample form the multivariate distribution, not exactly every time I run the code (I will be sampling whithin a loop) So I am assuming that line changes the initial internal state of `rng`? Where exactly should that line go?

Comment: It should already be different with each successive call.  Reseeding is only necessary to make it behave differently with each execution.  I can't think of what would make it behave otherwise.

Comment: So it should work fine as it is. Thank you very much for the code. But just out of curiosity, where exactly should I add the re-seeding line above? In the `sample` method of the class? or in the main program?

Comment: +1 nice code, I'm planning using it in an article of mine. I don't know much about algebra, but according to what I read in Wikipedia and Eigen's documentation, LDLT should work fine with matrices that are positive semi-definite, but not positive definite. See:

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1LDLT.html "Perform a robust Cholesky decomposition of a positive semidefinite or negative semidefinite".

But are you sure Robust Cholesky decomposition is OK there anyway? (in terms of producing correct results) Wikipedia says so, but with no references.